# takePicture callback data is null

Tags: android, camera, emulation

Is the `Camera.takePicture` callback for raw data null when running in emulator environment?
I got the `CameraSurface` method out of the WWW, so it should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to the raw-data callback only.
Using the picture callback which retrieves a jpeg solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Before calling takePicture you have to provide a buffer large enough to hold the raw image data. ([detailed here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)). For setting the buffer, use the addCallbackBuffer method.